# Create Custom Chatter Group

Tags: chatter

I'd like to create a Chatter Group that has certain publisher actions that only apply to that group type.

So suppose a Sales group has an action titled "Post Lead", and suppose a Marketing group has an action titled "Share Campaign".

So these actions only apply to the appropriate group, not all Chatter groups.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this declaratively. The layout for actions is either global (which applies to the user and record feed layouts) or group layout, which applies to all groups and not one specifically.

One option, although not exactly what you're looking for would be to create different group layouts for different profiles. It's important to point out though, that the same layout would apply for all users with that profile for all groups, and not separate layouts for each group.

Comment: Thanks. That's as I suspected. Putting it in the profile is a limited solution, eg in the hypothetical above, a non marketing person should still be able to share a campaign.